# Grok filter Pattern -Unable to get required values from Square bracket

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

Part of log sample entry given below

`[\"request_type\", \"post\"], [\"status_code\", 404], [\"u_id\", 111111]`

Need to get the values list post,404,111111 using grok, worked for below example

`[\"user_id\", 111111]` => `%{GREEDYDATA:A}, %{WORD:U_ID}\]` gives output as

```
  "A": [
    [
      "[\\"user_id\\""
    ]
  ],
  "U_ID": [
    [
      "111111"
    ]
  ]}
```

"
When trying to keep "user_id" and extract it's value using filter "

`[\"user_id\", %{WORD:U_ID}\]`

getting compile error or {}

Please let me know where the error or any thing missing filter pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the grok pattern that matches your log:

```
%{GREEDYDATA:no_use}%{POSINT:status_code}\]%{GREEDYDATA:no_use} %{POSINT:UID}\]
```

I have used the [Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to validate the grok pattern.

**Output:**

[image]